# micro-ros set domain ID micro-ros-agent to other than default 0

Tags: ros2

Following this https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_linux/ and using a raspberry pi4b as host and a pico, I'm able to build the project in a docker container on the pi, build the sample pico_micro_ros_example.uf2, load it into the pico and run the micro_ros_agent, which shows data being sent and received. However, no topic is published using ros2 topic list.

The rest of the ros2 system is set to ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1. When I set the system to ROS_DOMAIN_ID=0, then I see the /pico_publisher topic.

Question - where is the micro_ros_agent's ROS_DOMAIN_ID set to 0 where that can be changed to 1 for example.